# gedit indent guides

Tags: plugins, python, gedit

I would like some indent guides for gedit. This is very useful in python code. I couldn't find such an option in the settings, nor a plugin to add it. Does anyone know how to make such a thing visible? like I once had in SciTE, I want to see some small vertical lines visually indicating the indent level.

They must be customisable to appear between n spaces, usually 2 or 4, and should be visually quiet like 1 pixel width and light grey.

Comment: The same question was [asked on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794741/indent-guide-plugin-for-gedit-python). The answer links to a page that doesn't seem to exist anymore, but I think you should check out [this list of plugins](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/Plugins).

Comment: There's also a question on [unix.stackexchange.com on this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/163382/44760), but the situation even now seems to be so that someone should write such a plugin, as it doesn't exist...

Answer (score 1):

I found something that comes close to the description in the package 'gedit-plugins'.  The plugin is 'Draw Spaces'.  Just install the package, go to the 'Edit' tab in gedit, click on 'Preferences', go to the 'Plugins' tab, find this plugin, and there you have it.